# Handling EWF images with python

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I am currently searching for a good option to open an E01 image in Windows with Python and to see which folders and files are in there. Maybe you have some tips or a solution for me.

I just found options for Linux and some tool that still have bugs

By using pyewf im am able to decode the image and read the bytedata of the image.
I also found a package called haruspex which is a libary from a research paper with which i am able to retrive the [MBR of the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf5E0.png).

Now my question is how do i continue from here?
I need to convert the bytestream into a readable directory.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.